# Creating hour statistics using arrays and memcached

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, memcached

I am trying to count how many hits I have on my site each hour, but am not sure how to approach this.

Here is what i have now:

```
if($cacheAvailable == true){ // WE GOT A CACHE

    date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
    $thisHour = date("H", time());

    $moveStats = $memcache->get('moveStats');

    if(!$moveStats){
        $todayStats = array(array(hour => $thisHour, hits => 1, executetime => $total_time));
        $memcache->set('moveStats', $todayStats);
    } 


    foreach ($moveStats as $k => $v) {
        if($v['hour'] == $thisHour){
            $moveStats[$k]['hits']=$moveStats[$k]['hits']+1;
        }
    }

    $memcache->set('moveStats', $moveStats);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($moveStats);
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

This makes an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 18
            [hits] => 6
            [executetime] => 0
        )

)
```

//##### EDIT ######//

I am able to add to the current hour but I don't know how to add a new hour when the clock turns into the new hour?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Thought I could save you a few seconds with a small tip. `$thisHour = date("H", time());` will also work as `$thisHour = date("H");`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check if that index already exists, if not create a new one, and always increase the old value:

```
$todayStats = $moveStats;
if (!isset($todayStats [$thisHour])) {
    $todayStats[$thisHour] = 0;
}
$todayStats[$thisHour]['hits']++;
$todayStats[$thisHour]['executetime'] = $total_time;
```

But you have some other problems in your implementation:
 - Don't use string without quotes. That will try to call a constant with that name and only as fallback return the string itself. It also raises a notice.
 - $thisHour won't contain the current hour. If you really want to have the hour try: date('H') only.

Comment: I have used a little different approach and am not sure how to go from here. I have solved the first issue, but not sure how to solve the new problem. Please read my edited post!

Comment: The solution is still the same. First check if that hour is already set in the array and if not create it.